# Nodemon events.js 141 - unhandled error event

Tags: node.js, nodemon

Nodemon doesn't want to start up and I have absolutely no idea how to fix this.

[image]

Comment: I'm stuck here too -- no idea what happened.

Answer (score 3):

Just had this problem, but figured it out.

I had another application running on the same server (localhost:3000) and it threw this error. I stopped the other one (control-c) and tried it again on the new one and it worked. Perhaps you have another terminal window or tab open.

*(also, I couldn't comment but wanted to help so I just tried an answer)*

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't work in my case. I tried everything even so far as reinstalling node and nodemon. Still no dice. I "fixed" it by using supervisor for the time being

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in windows, that was due to not having "C:\Windows\System32" in the path variable. After adding the path variable it is working fine.

Try this Once.

Answer (score 0):

adding "C:\Windows\System32" to Path fixes it. I had this problem because I installed node by simply unzipping it as opposed to using the windows install package. I'm continuing my research as to way nodemon has this dependency.